# Trouble sending email from .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am re-writing an Access program in C#, MVC 4, .NET 4.  From my Access program I can send 300+ emails with no problem.  Here is the relavent code that is called from a loop:

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.From = FromEmail

If DebugMode Then
    objMessage.To = DebugEmail
Else
    objMessage.To = EmailStr
End If
If Not IsNull(BCCEmail) Then
    objMessage.bcc = BCCEmail
End If
objMessage.subject = subject
objMessage.HTMLbody = Message
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServerAddress
'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SMTPPort

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMessage.Send
```

In my MVC application I am having all sorts of problems.  Sometimes no emails are received.  Sometimes ~200 of the ~300 emails are received.  Somestimes only about twenty emails are received.  It all cases the emails are sent (according to the code) but never have all the emails been received back to my email client.  Here is the code from my MVC 4 program:

```
       using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            IList<Customer> customers = dbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.sendEmail == true).OrderBy(c => c.boxNumber).ToList();
            Setting setting = dbContext.Settings.First();

            SmtpClient smptClient = new SmtpClient();
            //smptClient.Timeout = 1000 * 200;  // setting the timeout to 200 seconds.
            DateTime batchTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

            Customer customer;
            for (int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++ )
            {
                customer = (Customer)customers[i];
                MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage();

                setEmailRecipients(customer, ref emailMessage);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(setting.bccEmail))
                    emailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(setting.bccEmail));

                emailMessage.Subject = "Box #" + customer.boxNumber + ".  " + setting.emailSubject;
                emailMessage.Body = setting.emailBody;
                try
                {
                    smptClient.Send(emailMessage);
                }
                catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(smtpEx, "EmailError");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 100);   // wait for 100 seconds
                    i--; // backup the counter so the same email is resent
                    continue;
                }

                customer.sendEmail = false;  // Clear the customer's email sent flag

                EmailHistory history = new EmailHistory();
                history.sentTo = customer.email;
                history.boxNumber = customer.boxNumber;
                history.sentOn = DateTime.Now;
                history.batchTimeStamp = batchTimeStamp;
                dbContext.EmailHistories.Add(history);

                dbContext.SaveChanges();

                //if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0)
                //    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 20);    // sleep to 20 seconds.

            }
        }
```

I'm totally stumped.  Can someone tell me why I'm the C# code will not work?

EDIT:  I think I found the problem.  I moved call to instantiate my SmtpClient object inside the loop in a "using" clause.  So the SmtpClient is instantiated and then destroyed for each email.  I thought instantiating the SmtpClient over and over like this is a no-no but it works.  Anybody know why?

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to see if any exceptions are thrown and why?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain this is the true cause, but you have a potential infinite loop here:

```
catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(smtpEx, "EmailError");
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 100);   // wait for 100 seconds
    i--; // backup the counter so the same email is resent
    continue;
}
```

If there is an exception caused by bad inputs (like a bad email address?), and those inputs won't change from loop to loop, then this will loop infinitely.

Comment: You are correct about an infinite loop.  This code is mainly for debugging purposes.  Once I confirm all emails are sent correctly I'll probably remove this.

Answer (score 1):

Is your web.config file setup properly? See [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/432854) for a good working example.

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="test@foo.com">
        <network host="smtpserver1" port="25" userName="username" password="secret" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

From a design perspective, you may want to see about moving your business logic - including both e-mail and database save - into a service (e.g. using [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)) so that it is running in a separate process from the web site. This separation of layers will also improve the extensibility and testability of your code.